# transport message failed, response body in Annroid(AOSP)cuttlefish

Tags: android, android-source

Unable to launch cuttlefish emulator for AOSP12 in ubuntu20.04.

Followed below steps :

$ repo init -u https://android.googlesource.com/platform/manifest -b android-12.0.0_r26

$ repo sync -c

$ source build/envsetup.sh

$ lunch aosp_cf_x86_phone-userdebug

$ launch_cvd -start_webrtc

```
=================================================================== 
NOTICE:

We collect usage statistics in accordance with our
Content Licenses (https://source.android.com/setup/start/licenses),
Contributor License Agreement (https://cla.developers.google.com/),
Privacy Policy (https://policies.google.com/privacy) and
Terms of Service (https://policies.google.com/terms).
===================================================================

launch_cvd I 11-14 20:43:58 16499 16499 launch_cvd.cc:184] Host changed from last run: 0
assemble_cvd D 11-14 20:43:58 16850 16850 fetcher_config.cpp:212] Could not find file ending in kernel
assemble_cvd D 11-14 20:43:58 16850 16850 fetcher_config.cpp:212] Could not find file ending in initramfs.img
assemble_cvd I 11-14 20:43:58 16850 16850 flags.cc:822] Launching CVD using --config='phone'.
assemble_cvd D 11-14 20:43:58 16850 16850 subprocess.cpp:266] Started (pid: 16853): /home/test/aosp/base-AOSP12/out/soong/host/linux-x86/bin/extract-ikconfig
assemble_cvd D 11-14 20:43:58 16850 16850 subprocess.cpp:268] /home/test/aosp/base-AOSP12/out/target/product/vsoc_x86/boot.img
MESA-INTEL: warning: Performance support disabled, consider sysctl dev.i915.perf_stream_paranoid=0

MESA-INTEL: warning: Performance support disabled, consider sysctl dev.i915.perf_stream_paranoid=0

GPU auto mode: did not detect prerequisites for accelerated rendering support, enabling --gpu_mode=guest_swiftshader.
Point your browser to https://0.0.0.0:8443 to interact with the device.
Serial console is disabled; use -console=true to enable it
The following files contain useful debugging information:
Launcher log: /home/test/cuttlefish_runtime.1/launcher.log
Android's logcat output: /home/test/cuttlefish_runtime.1/logcat
Kernel log: /home/test/cuttlefish_runtime.1/kernel.log
Instance configuration: /home/test/cuttlefish_runtime.1/cuttlefish_config.json
Instance environment: /home/test/.cuttlefish.sh
failed to read from socket, retry.
[2022/11/14 20:44:01:2460] N:  Vhost 'localhost' using TLS mode
Start modem simulator, server_fds: 7, Sim type: normal
[2022/11/14 20:44:01:2477] N: openssl is too old to support lws_tls_vhost_cert_info   
2022-11-14 20:44:01.250 bluetooth - 
system/bt/vendor_libs/test_vendor_lib/model/setup/device_boutique.cc:33 - Register: 
Registering beacon_swarm
2022-11-14 20:44:01.250 bluetooth - system/bt/vendor_libs/test_vendor_lib/model/setup/device_boutique.cc:33 - Register: Registering beacon
2022-11-14 20:44:01.250 bluetooth - system/bt/vendor_libs/test_vendor_lib/model/setup/device_boutique.cc:33 - Register: Registering scripted_beacon
 2022-11-14 20:44:01.250 bluetooth - system/bt/vendor_libs/test_vendor_lib/model/setup/device_boutique.cc:33 - Register: Registering remote_loopback
  2022-11-14 20:44:01.250 bluetooth - system/bt/vendor_libs/test_vendor_lib/model/setup/device_boutique.cc:33 - Register: Registering car_kit
 2022-11-14 20:44:01.250 bluetooth - system/bt/vendor_libs/test_vendor_lib/model/setup/device_boutique.cc:33 - Register: Registering classic
   2022-11-14 20:44:01.250 bluetooth - system/bt/vendor_libs/test_vendor_lib/model/setup/device_boutique.cc:33 - Register: Registering sniffer
    2022-11-14 20:44:01.250 bluetooth - system/bt/vendor_libs/test_vendor_lib/model/setup/device_boutique.cc:33 - Register: Registering keyboard
        
     
    2022-11-14 20:44:01.251 bluetooth - system/bt/vendor_libs/test_vendor_lib/desktop/root_canal_main.cc:86 - main: main
    
    2022-11-14 20:44:01.251 bluetooth - system/bt/vendor_libs/test_vendor_lib/desktop/root_canal_main.cc:93 - main: 0: /home/test/aosp/base-AOSP12/out/soong/host/linux-x86/bin/root-canal (0)
    
     2022-11-14 20:44:01.251 bluetooth - system/bt/vendor_libs/test_vendor_lib/desktop/root_canal_main.cc:93 - main: 1: 7500 (7500)
    
    2022-11-14 20:44:01.251 bluetooth - system/bt/vendor_libs/test_vendor_lib/desktop/root_canal_main.cc:93 - main: 2: 7300 (7300)
    
     2022-11-14 20:44:01.251 bluetooth - system/bt/vendor_libs/test_vendor_lib/desktop/root_canal_main.cc:93 - main: 3: 7400 (7400)
     
     2022-11-14 20:44:01.251 bluetooth - system/bt/vendor_libs/test_vendor_lib/model/devices/device_properties.cc:80 - DeviceProperties: Reading controller properties from /home/test/aosp/base-AOSP12/out/soong/host/linux-x86/etc/rootcanal/data/controller_properties.json.
```

android.hardware.automotive.vehicle@2.0-virtualization-grpc-server E 11-14 20:44:01 17313 17335 GarageModeServerSideHandler.cpp:131] operator(): marker file /home/test/cuttlefish_runtime.1/power_state has not been created yet.

```
     2022-11-14 20:44:01.253 bluetooth - system/bt/vendor_libs/test_vendor_lib/model/devices/device_properties.cc:80 - DeviceProperties: Reading controller properties from /etc/bluetooth/car_kit_controller_properties.json.
     
     2022-11-14 20:44:01.253 bluetooth - system/bt/vendor_libs/test_vendor_lib/model/devices/device_properties.cc:82 - DeviceProperties: Error reading controller properties from file.
     
     2022-11-14 20:44:01.253 bluetooth - system/bt/vendor_libs/test_vendor_lib/model/devices/scripted_beacon.cc:71 - ScriptedBeacon: Scripted_beacon registered true
     
     2022-11-14 20:44:01.253 bluetooth - system/bt/vendor_libs/test_vendor_lib/desktop/test_environment.cc:36 - initialize: 
     
      2022-11-14 20:44:01.253 bluetooth - system/bt/vendor_libs/test_vendor_lib/model/setup/test_channel_transport.cc:48 - SetUp: port: 7500
     
     2022-11-14 20:44:01.253 bluetooth - system/bt/vendor_libs/test_vendor_lib/desktop/test_environment.cc:158 - operator(): No test channel: RegisterSendResponse called
     
      2022-11-14 20:44:01.253 bluetooth - system/bt/vendor_libs/test_vendor_lib/desktop/test_environment.cc:158 - operator(): No test channel: set timer period to 5
      
      2022-11-14 20:44:01.253 bluetooth - system/bt/vendor_libs/test_vendor_lib/model/setup/test_model.cc:88 - StartTimer: StartTimer()
      
      2022-11-14 20:44:01.254 bluetooth - system/bt/vendor_libs/test_vendor_lib/desktop/test_environment.cc:158 - operator(): No test channel: timer started
      
      2022-11-14 20:44:01.254 bluetooth - system/bt/vendor_libs/test_vendor_lib/model/setup/test_command_handler.cc:140 - Add: Add beacon@be:ac:01:55:00:01
      
      2022-11-14 20:44:01.254 bluetooth - system/bt/vendor_libs/test_vendor_lib/desktop/test_environment.cc:158 - operator(): No test channel: 0:beacon@be:ac:01:55:00:01
      
      2022-11-14 20:44:01.254 bluetooth - system/bt/vendor_libs/test_vendor_lib/desktop/test_environment.cc:158 - operator(): No test channel: TestCommandHandler 'add_device_to_phy' called with device 0 and phy 1
      
      2022-11-14 20:44:01.254 bluetooth - system/bt/vendor_libs/test_vendor_lib/model/setup/test_command_handler.cc:140 - Add: Add beacon@be:ac:01:55:00:02
      
      2022-11-14 20:44:01.254 bluetooth - system/bt/vendor_libs/test_vendor_lib/desktop/test_environment.cc:158 - operator(): No test channel: 1:beacon@be:ac:01:55:00:02
       
      2022-11-14 20:44:01.254 bluetooth - system/bt/vendor_libs/test_vendor_lib/desktop/test_environment.cc:158 - operator(): No test channel: TestCommandHandler 'add_device_to_phy' called with device 1 and phy 1
      
      2022-11-14 20:44:01.254 bluetooth - system/bt/vendor_libs/test_vendor_lib/desktop/test_environment.cc:172 - SetUpTestChannel: Test channel SetUp() successful
     
      2022-11-14 20:44:01.254 bluetooth - system/bt/vendor_libs/test_vendor_lib/model/setup/test_channel_transport.cc:48 - SetUp: port: 7300
      
      2022-11-14 20:44:01.254 bluetooth - system/bt/vendor_libs/test_vendor_lib/desktop/test_environment.cc:75 - operator(): No HCI Response channel: RegisterSendResponse called
      
     2022-11-14 20:44:01.254 bluetooth - system/bt/vendor_libs/test_vendor_lib/model/setup/test_channel_transport.cc:48 - SetUp: port: 7400 
    
     2022-11-14 20:44:01.254 bluetooth - system/bt/vendor_libs/test_vendor_lib/desktop/test_environment.cc:101 - operator(): No LinkLayer Response channel: RegisterSendResponse called
  
     2022-11-14 20:44:01.254 bluetooth - system/bt/vendor_libs/test_vendor_lib/desktop/test_environment.cc:63 - initialize: initialize: Finished
```

WaylandServer running on socket 15
(adm_helpers.cc:48): Unable to access speaker.
[WARNING:external/crosvm/src/linux.rs:2842] Unable to open low mem margin, maybe not a chrome os kernel

```
      [2022/11/14 20:44:01:3042] N: accepting self-signed certificate (verify_callback)
```

Creating handler for /register_device
Registered device: 'cvd-1'
GUEST_UBOOT_VERSION: 2021.01-07989-g74c21be757 (May 10 2021 - 19:57:34 +0000)

```
       2022-11-14 20:44:02.245 bluetooth - system/bt/vendor_libs/test_vendor_lib/model/setup/test_channel_transport.cc:92 - Accept: accept_fd = 8.
      
       2022-11-14 20:44:02.245 bluetooth - system/bt/vendor_libs/test_vendor_lib/model/devices/device_properties.cc:80 - DeviceProperties: Reading controller properties from /etc/bluetooth/controller_properties.json.
      
       2022-11-14 20:44:02.245 bluetooth - system/bt/vendor_libs/test_vendor_lib/model/devices/device_properties.cc:82 - DeviceProperties: Error reading controller properties from file.
      
       2022-11-14 20:44:02.246 bluetooth - system/bt/vendor_libs/test_vendor_lib/model/setup/test_model.cc:199 - IncomingHciConnection: initialized da:4c:10:de:17:02
       
       transport message failed, response body: 

       transport message failed, response body: 

       transport message failed, response body: 

       transport message failed, response body: 
       
       transport message failed, response body: 

       transport message failed, response body: 
       
       transport message failed, response body: 
       
       transport message failed, response body: 

       transport message failed, response body:
```

Followed below blog :
https://2net.co.uk/blog/cuttlefish-android12.html

Comment: do you find any solution? I have the same error but in my case is related to this issue https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/228795137

Comment: Yes, it is working fine with the master branch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just dowloaded the branch master and it worked:

$repo init -u https://android.googlesource.com/platform/manifest -b master

but in this case will download Android 13.